# SQL Employee table with concatenated direct reports hierarchy

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an employee table with the structure shown below. I'm trying to build a column with comma separated values which are direct reports to the employee. I've used manager names to easily understand. The actual data has IDs.

```
EMPID     NAME     MANAGER_1     MANAGER_2     MANAGER_3     MANAGER_4.......     MANAGER_30
A3456     JOHN     MEGAN         DEREK         MIKE          NULL
S4593     ASHTON   MEGAN         DEREK         MIKE          NULL
G8394     MICHAEL  MEGAN         DEREK         MIKE          NULL
D9038     MIKE     MEGAN         DEREK         NULL
J4890     DEREK    MEGAN         NULL
M4940     MEGAN    NULL
```

The hierarchy is as follows
JOHN's immediate manager is Mike, Mike reports to Derek, Derek reports to Megan
ASHTON's immediate manager is Mike, Mike reports to Derek, Derek reports to Megan.

I'm trying to build a new column which will create a comma separted list of direct reports
eg: for MIKE direct reports will be JOHN, ASHTON, MICHAEL
for DEREK direct reports will be MIKE

**Expected result**

```
EMPID     NAME     MANAGER_1     MANAGER_2     MANAGER_3     MANAGER_4.......     Direct Reports     
A3456     JOHN     MEGAN         DEREK         MIKE          NULL                 NULL          
S4593     ASHTON   MEGAN         DEREK         MIKE          NULL                 NULL          
G8394     MICHAEL  MEGAN         DEREK         MIKE          NULL                 NULL          
D9038     MIKE     MEGAN         DEREK         NULL                               JOHN, ASHTON, MICHAEL
J4890     DEREK    MEGAN         NULL                                             MIKE
M4940     MEGAN    NULL                                                           MEGAN
```

To build this in SQL should I use partition logic?

Comment: With this schema, such task will be tedious. You would rather store each emp/manager relation on a separate row rather than in multiple columns. Then you could use a hierarchical query.

Comment: @GMB - I'll bet this is PeopleSoft. I've seen this kind of nonsense before.

Comment: @GMB - Yes it is! I looked at this table structure and it had 30 Columns for Manager hierarchy. I was like really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty easy - just use coalesce:

This query will give you what you need:

```sql
select 
   coalesce(MANAGER_30, MANAGER_29,...MANAGER_1) NAME
  ,listagg(name,',')within group(order by name) "Direct Reports"
grom your_table
group by 
   coalesce(MANAGER_30, MANAGER_29,...MANAGER_1)
```

You just will need to left join results to your original query.

PS. But such structure is very inconvenient. I'd suggest normal hierarchy table with parent->child relationship